# Warning C4232: nonstandard extension used.. address of dllimport 'func' is not static, identity not guaranteed

Tags: c, dll

I have a DLL(call it DLL1) (c language) with two files:

- file1.h
- file1.c

In `file1.h` I have:

```
void func(void);
```

In `file1.c` I have:

```
#include "file.h"    
void func() { /* implementation */}
```

---

In DLL2 I have a `file2.c` that includes `file1.h` and has an array of functions like this:

```
const void* arr[1] = { func };
```

An array that holds pointers to some functions ( one function in this example) from other DLLs.

I get the warning:

```
warning C4232: nonstandard extension used : 'void *' : address of dllimport 'func' is not static, identity not guaranteed
```

Is there any solution for this? To make the address of this function as static/const?
I've tried using `__declspec( dllimport )` and `__declspec( dllexport )` but it didn't help

Comment: What happens if you change to consistent `void func(void) { /* implementation */}`?

Comment: The same warning

Comment: It is a pretty quibbly warning, normal for level 4 warnings.  Nothing actually goes wrong, the MSVC compiler and linker know how to handle this and make the array entry relocatable.  But if you ever port this to another toolset then it might not work as expected.  Compiling DLLs with /Za in effect is not terribly sensible, the standard does not at all prescribe how they are supposed to work.

Comment: You are right, it works fine.
But our team have changed the compiler to treat warnings as errors, so this is not good now

Comment: They changed more than that, the default warning level is 3.  You'll have to discuss with your team how they'll want to deal with warnings that don't actually produce bad code.  The alternative code is quite ugly, GetProcAddress() never makes code better.  Having to suppress warnings at /W4 is normal.